# How to run expo start with release-channels

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to try running my react native app locally but against my staging and/or production server. I'm looking to do this by setting a `release-channel` variable when I run `expo start`. I hope this can test/foreshadow some performance in beta and production.

I tried the command `expo start --release-channel staging` and I got an error `error: unknown option '--release-channel'`

How can I set `Constants.manifest.releaseChannel` when I run expo start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables don't exist explicitly, but you can utilize release channels to make that happen!
Say you have a workflow of releasing builds like this:

```
expo publish --release-channel staging-v1
```

For standalone apps:

Build your standalone app by running

```
expo build:ios --release-channel <your-channel>
expo build:android --release-channel <your-channel>
```

You can access the channel your release is published under with the releaseChannel field in the [manifest object.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/#expoconstantsmanifest)
Constants.manifest.releaseChannel does NOT exist in dev mode. It does exist, however when you explicitly publish / build with it.

Here is a detailed description of [this answer.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/release-channels/)

Comment: Thjat doesn't tell how to start expo web with the release-channel and that's 100% production part of expo.

Answer (score 0):

To those who also try to use environment within `expo` but for the web target,

My solution is to use `cp` to overwrite the `prod` configuration in `prebuild` script:

```
# fix --release-channel not available for web yet
cp -f src/config/env/staging.js src/config/env/prod.js
```

> I also got tips from expo tips that the `--release-channel` feature is not available for web, this is the only way I have found so far.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native run-android --variant=release` & `react-native run-ios --configuration Release` maybe would help :)