# React Native Mobile Application Crashing in TestFlight but works properly in Expo Go

Tags: react-native, testflight, mobile-application

Our mobile application developed in React Native was tested using Expo Go and works as expected. However, when we transitioned to deployment and testing with TestFlight, we discovered that a specific button was causing the app to crash in testflight. Has anyone else experienced something like this before? Below is the crash log we get. (Inserted [redacted] for privacy)

```
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: [redacted] [5827]
Triggered by Thread:  2
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x198ee269c __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x191177c80 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   [redacted]                             0x100a34fd4 0x1008e8000 + 1363924
3   [redacted]                             0x100aa32b0 0x1008e8000 + 1815216
4   [redacted]                             0x100aa3ae4 0x1008e8000 + 1817316
5   CoreFoundation                         0x198e27794 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                         0x198e2722c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
7   CoreFoundation                         0x198e27054 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
8   [redacted]                             0x100a644c4 0x1008e8000 + 1557700
9   [redacted]                             0x100a66514 0x1008e8000 + 1565972
10  [redacted]                             0x100a66164 0x1008e8000 + 1565028
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0deb6a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ded300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df4894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df53c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0e00004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0dff878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1b964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1ba04 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0555178 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0554f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0554e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0554c68 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x198e2bb1c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x198e29a14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x198e29478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   GraphicsServices                       0x1dc3aa4f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
8   UIKitCore                              0x19b24d62c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9   UIKitCore                              0x19b24cc68 UIApplicationMain + 340
10  [redacted]                             0x1008efa3c 0x1008e8000 + 31292
11  dyld                                   0x1bbb62dcc start + 2240
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1b9fc start_wqthread + 0
Thread 2 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e055dfbc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1f680 pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a0ea5b90 abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d49ff8 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d39f90 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19117ada4 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d493bc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d49360 std::terminate() + 108
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ded314 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df4894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df53c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0e00004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0dff878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1b964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1ba04 start_wqthread + 8
```

Not really sure where to start/what to expect here and how to resolve our issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is only reproducible when the app is running with a release flag. I'm not familiar with Expo that much but using react-native-cli you can do two things.

1. `react-native run-ios --mode Release` (This way you can run the application in release mode and check the logs in XCode directly)
2. This is a bit more complex but you can bundle you're current js code with `react-native bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios` then you can **start your metro server** run the application and **kill the metro server**, the idea is that the application now will load the **bundle created from the first command** and you will probably be able to reproduce the issue.

This might be helpful - [How to run expo start with release-channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475965/how-to-run-expo-start-with-release-channels)